# Show lines segments parallel?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Based on the attached, if $AB$ and $DC$ are parallel, then $$\frac{|OD|}{|OA|}=\frac{|OC|}{|OB|}=\frac{|CD|}{|AB|}$$ Using the theorem, how can I show the following when the image is dilated by a dilation factor of $r$:

**The line segments go to parallel line segments**

I am not sure what this question is asking. I thought it was saying to show that $rAB$ and $rDC$ are parallel (so kind of the theorem in reverse). If so, can I show that the lines are parallel proceeding by contradiction and assuming they're not? So then, if the lines aren't parallel, then they must intersect at some point, $p$? 
Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we dilate everything by a factor of $r$, then the ratios
$$\frac{|OD|}{|OA|}=\frac{|OC|}{|OB|}=\frac{|CD|}{|AB|}$$
will continue to hold, right? Have you learned that that is a sufficient condition for $AB$ and $CD$ to be parallel?

In particular, you can show that $OAB$ and $ODC$ are similar triangles (try Side angle side), and therefore angle $OAB$ and angle $ODC$ are the same.

Comment: Someone asked me this question, so I'm not sure if I can assume that. I did show the first part of your statement though. If I can't assume your second statement, how can I prove it?

Comment: @Alti I added some.

Comment: Thank you. So, it wouldn't be correct to prove by showing they don't intersect?

Comment: @Alti Not to say that that is an incorrect method, but I don't see how to do it that way.

Comment: I would assume they intersect at a point, $p$. Then, I was thinking to use the parallel lines before dilation to show (by contradiction) that they can't intersect...

Comment: @Alti That seems like it would work.